# Blazor: Component doesn't update every time the for loop spins

Tags: c#, .net, razor, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am currently working on a Blazor project and facing with a bug. The plan is to update a component in every second, as long as the for loop updates. My problem is a bit complex, so I reproduced this bug in another project:

The Calculate.cs file where the calculations happen:

```
public class Calculate
{
    public void Calc(Index index)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            index.Update(i);
        }
    }
}
```

The index.razor file:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="Test">Click me</button>

<p>Test number: @testNumber</p>

@code
{
    private int testNumber;
    Calculate c = new Calculate();

    public void Test()
    {
        c.Calc(this);   
    }
    public void Update(int i)
    {
        testNumber = i;
        Debug.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

After testing, the Debug Console prints the numbers as it should in every second, all the way from 0-9, but the opened Blazor display only prints the 9, whenever the calculations and the 10 seconds are over.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve by your current design. However, in a real-world app you should make your Calculate class a service which you can inject into your component, and this service can implement the State pattern and the Notification pattern. Generally speaking, your service provides services to your components such as calculations, and when they are ready, it should invoke an event delegate to notify subscribers of the event, and pass them event args if necessary, as for instance, the result of calculation.

Comment: And you certainly must not pass an instance of the component to a class so that it can call the components methods. Again, expose events. This is how we have been coding for ages.

Answer (score 3):

This will only work when you can make the process async.

To do that, move the for-loop to the Test() method, and make that a Task returning method. The razor code can stay as-is.

```
public Task Test()
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
       await Task.Run( _ =>  c.CalcSubTask(this));   

       Update(i);        
       StateHasChanged();
       await Task.Delay(1);
   }
}
```

and note that this will only perform acceptably in Blazor/Server. In a Wasm project you only have 1 thread and this would lock up your UI.

---

On a second thought, you could  keep the current structure by making the Calc methods async too and `await` the Update() method. Update() can then await the Task.Delay(1).

Make sure you have a valid await chain from your Test() method through the Calc methods and back to Update().

The update method would look like

```
public async Task Update(int i)
{
    testNumber = i;
    Debug.WriteLine(i);
    await InvokeAsync(StatHasChanged);  // could be running on another Thread
    await Task.Delay(1);
}
```

Comment: This second one is the one I needed, and it works! Thank you!

Comment: The `await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged());` line gives me "cannot convert from void to System.Action" error. Is it okay just using `StateHasChanged();`?

Comment: I had a typo, but that is the wrong correction. See the edit changes.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your for loop code.

```
StateHasChanged();
```

Forces a refresh.

I have a sample that does simple animations if you want to look at my sprite component:

https://github.com/DataJuggler/DataJuggler.Blazor.Components

And a video is here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=frtetHgfdIo

Comment: Yeah, I have already tried to use StateHasChanged() but reached no improvement with it unfortunately. Literally seems that nothing changes with the system, if I add StateHasChanged() :/

Comment: Having same issue. Ex. After making api call, looping items and setting IsChecked = false, but they stay checked in the UI. Tried StateHasChanged() and using InvokeAsync() to no avail. Did you solve this/

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to assign `i`'s value to a temp variable inside the for-loop like below?:

```
var counter = i;
index.Update(counter);
```