# UI Update on .net MAUI + Blazor hybrid

Tags: blazor, .net-maui, maui-blazor

I have this app that upload files from local hard drive. Everything is working fine but I can't get to work the UI update so the user know how the upload is going.

In my blazor page I have this:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@(async () => await ProcessFiles())" disabled="@processStatus.IsRunning">Procesar</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@(() => { showEditForm = true; })" disabled="@disableEditButton">Editar</button>

    @if (processStatus.IsRunning)
    {
        <div class="alert alert-warning my-sm-2" role="alert">
            <img src="Images/loading.gif" width="50" alt="Cargando..."> Cargando ficheros @currentFileProcessed...
        </div>
    }
```

And in my class I have this:

```
async Task ProcessFiles()
        {
            processStatus.IsRunning = true;
            var progressReporter = new Progress<string>(ReportProgress);
            var spConfig = CurrentContext.GetFromContext<SharePointConfig>("SharePointConfig");
            await uploadService.Upload(fileList, spConfig, processStatus, progressReporter);
        }

        void ReportProgress(string message)
        {
            currentFileProcessed = message;
        }
```

I'm able to see the process updates the value in currentFileProcessed but the UI only updates after everything is finished. I guess my UI is getting blocked but I can's see how to get this done. I have tried changing the delegate making it async as well but with no luck.

Comment: You can try to show the progress of the upload with the progress bar, just like [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62804855/how-to-upload-files-and-see-a-progress-bar).

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT, thanks for the tip but I'm not looking for a progress bar but for lettimg the user know what file is being uplopaded. So the problem still remains, I'm able to get information from the async method using the IProgress object but a can't get the UI to be updated even if it's still responsive and let's me click on the menu, etc.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, did you try to use the `StateHasChanged();` to notify the UI？

Comment: OIC, sorry I didn't notice what you meant!! It works!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to call the `StateHasChanged()` method to notify the UI. Such as:

```
void ReportProgress(string message)
    {
        currentFileProcessed = message;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
```

If you need more information, please check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60799296/blazor-component-doesnt-update-every-time-the-for-loop-spins).